# Foursquare API for nearby places iPhone

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I want to get the nearby place by passing the current lat-long.
And want to get photos of that place.

I have got this link:

http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json?geolat=40.82&geolong=-74.1&l=50&q=pizza

But it is showing me 
[Error page](https://developer.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json)

How do i get this error solved?

Please help me and suggest a FourSquare API URL which will help me to get the place information and photos of current lat-long.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on a similar app...

Use [API explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore) to create and test the string you'd like to use

As Gilbert said, you have to use v2, this is an example of a valid link...

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=45.49,15.59&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735&radius=3000&oauth_token=A5ZDWL2DLXPZCQ3ZJESVOAKDMPQHSNNVWC3UMVOUOXPQHWRT&v=20121105

As you can see, you also must have `&oauth_token=A5ZDWL2DLXPZCQ3ZJESVOAKDMPQHSNNVWC3UMVOUOXPQHWRT&v=20121105` at the end of the URL link...

When you're in an API Explorer copy the link below the textbox and it should work...

Take a look here:[image: API EXPLORER example]

Answer (score 3):

The v1 API is no longer functional. You'll need to use v2.
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But is there any way to get the photos or  the images of the nearby place...As by using the above url i am only getting the icon image...

Comment: Check out the other endpoints documented at the site linked to by Gilbert. You can photos, tips, the mayor, etc.